# Running winforms in task bar

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I have a winforms application that I want to display an icon, and display the icon next to the icons on my taksbar for like my AV sofware, and the volume control.  Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to look at the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx).

Couple of quick things you can do.  When a user minimizes your application, you can "hide" it instead( this.Hide() ).  Then on the click of the NotifyIcon, you can show your application.

Comment: +1 for NotifyIcon, you can also use SharpDevelop and get a pre-packaged NotifyIcon project.